# Trying to download file in Google Storage return json

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to download a file from Google Storage.
If I access Google Storage page, I can download the file correctly.

But if I try to use an api to download, its returning an json object:

```
 {
    "kind": "storage#object",
    "id": "storage-key/file/id",
    "selfLink": "link",
    "name": "name.xlsx",
    "bucket": "bucketName",
    "generation": "35452344234",
    "metageneration": "1",
    "contentType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "timeCreated": "2017-02-23T12:35:04.258Z",
    "updated": "2017-02-23T12:35:04.258Z",
    "storageClass": "STANDARD",
    "timeStorageClassUpdated": "2017-02-23T12:35:04.258Z",
    "size": "4679",
    "md5Hash": "k3A546723454afhjgrfKuZw==",
    "mediaLink": "medialink",
    "crc32c": "U2ajDQ==",
    "etag": "DMiAt62dbtICAAE="
}
```

I'm basicly using:

```
import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
storage.objects().get(bucketName, fileName).executeAsInputStream();
```

And yesterday it worked :.
Do you have any ideia of why its returning a json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

executeAsInputStream() [retrieves the object's metadata](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.19.1/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest) (as a stream).

executeMediaAsInputStream() retrieves the object's contents (as a stream).

Also, you may be interested in switching to the new [google-cloud client library for Java](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/index.html), which removes some of the more confusing bits of the client you're using. Here's an [example of how to use it for downloading](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/examples/storage/StorageExample.java#L356).